# Style font for input field (Angularjs)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, validation

here is the plunker link-> http://plnkr.co/edit/iFnjcq?p=preview

As you can see in the link, it performs validation of input field. only numbers are allowed to enter and it adds commas automatically.

My question is-> if i give a negative number in that field, how can i change the color of the value entered in that field automatically.

i.e A positive number should display as it is. when user enters negative, numbers get entered with red color of the text.

Is there any way i can achieve this guys ??

HTML-

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="amount" format="number" />
</div>
```

JS directive

```
var app = angular.module('App',[]);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) { 
});

app.directive('format', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
return {
    require: 'ngModel',

    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
        if (!ctrl) return;


        ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function (a) {
            return $filter(attrs.format)(ctrl.$modelValue);
        });


        ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
            var plainNumber = viewValue.replace(/[^\d|\-+]/g, '');
            elem.val($filter('number')(plainNumber/100,2));
            return plainNumber;
        });
    }
};
}]);
```

Regarding the style overwrite issue discussed below, here is the problem.

The actual HTML Code

```
<div class="Ip"><input type="text" ng-model="amount" format="number" /></div>
```

The CSS is applied through scss for the class Ip. Here it is

```
$font:#fff;    //this font gets overwritten. even if i exclude this font of bootstrap is there which will overwite the class mentioned in directive. 

.inputCl{
        color:$font;
}

.Ip{                     
    input{
          @extend .inputCl;                         
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you apply the formatting just check to see if it negative and add a css class as necessary

```
ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
        var plainNumber = viewValue.replace(/[^\d|\-+]/g, '');
        elem.val($filter('number')(plainNumber/100,2));
        if (plainNumber < 0) {
           elem.addClass('negative');
        } else {
            elem.removeClass('negative');
        }
        return plainNumber;
    });
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/GdneR70Rw6RtTbwMrfx4?p=preview

Your SASS

```
$font:#fff; 
$fontNegative:#ff0000;   

.inputCl{
    color:$font;
}

.Ip{                     
    input{
          @extend .inputCl;                         
    }
    input.negative {
         color: $fontNegative;    
    }

}
```

Comment: this input type is inside a div. so css of div is overwriting  to the css mentioned by us in the directive. How can i not let it overwrite ?

Comment: can you post the css you are using? CSS has a concept of specificity where the CSS with the highest specificity will "win". I would need to see your css to see what might be causing the override issue.

Comment: @mcgraphix- edited the question to provide more overview on the overwrite problem i am facing.

Comment: This should do it then: 
.Ip input.negative { color: #ff0000}

Comment: i got confused a bit. where should i set this ?

Comment: I'm not an expert on SASS but I think in your case it would be:  $font:#fff;    //this font gets overwritten. even if i exclude this font of bootstrap is there which will overwite the class mentioned in directive. 

.inputCl{
        color:$font;
}

.Ip{                     
    input{
          @extend .inputCl;                         
    }
input.negative {
    color: #ff0000;
}

}

Comment: should i mention elem.addClass(".spnIp input.negative"); in directive then ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97031/discussion-between-mcgraphix-and-ayesha).

Answer (score 1):

You could add couple of conditions to your existing `format` directive, but this is not cool: directive should be focused and does its own single thing, like formatting.

Instead, create one more very simple directive to just add new validation constraint. Let's call it `positive` directive:

```
.directive('positive', [function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            if (!ctrl) return;
            ctrl.$validators.positive = function(value) {
                return value && value >= 0;
            };
        }
    };
}]);
```

then the usage would be

```
<input type="text" ng-model="amount" format="number" positive />
```

After that you can style valid/invalid state of the input using `.ng-invalid-positive` class that will be added by Angular for your depending on the current input:

```
.ng-invalid-positive {
    color: red;
}
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/2RAlx0DoFH1HEmdT0XCv?p=preview

Comment: @dfsq- this input type is inside a div. so css of div is overwriting  to the css mentioned by us in the directive. How can i not let it overwrite ?