# Negative value validation in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I am using input type="number" but I am getting the view as up and down value bars in the text box. How to avoid this?
How can I validate a negative value in the input text box?. If I enter a negative value as input then proper error message should display.

Comment: I wrote this simple directive recently for another question, exactly for your purpose: validating positive numbers. Check it out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34095586/949476

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790935/can-i-hide-the-html5-number-input-s-spin-box And for negative numbers You can write a filter that catches minus sign and gives the error message .

Answer (score 3):

> but I am getting the view as up and down value bars in the text box. How to avoid this?

You can remove those spinner buttons in some browsers with simple CSS:

```
input[type='number'] {
    -moz-appearance:textfield;
}
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

(credits to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22559163/949476)). It will not work in IE though.

Now real question, how to validate user input? Angular solution in this case would be creating additional validation directive. Here is the simple one I recently wrote:

```js
angular.module('demo', []).directive('positive', [function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            if (!ctrl) return;
            ctrl.$validators.positive = function(value) {
                return value && value >= 0;
            };
        }
    };
}]);
```

```css
input[type='number'] {
    -moz-appearance:textfield;
}
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.error {color: brown;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="demo">
    
    <form name="paymentForm">
        <input type="number" name="amount" ng-model="amount" positive />
    </form>
    
    <div class="error" ng-show="paymentForm.amount.$error.positive">Amount should be positive number.</div>
</div>
```